# Different X-frame Options for different sitecore sites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

There are three site categories and non of them can be identified using the template or a specific field. The only way that can be identified is using the site start path (defined in the sites config) of each sitecore website item.

Can some one help me to add different x-frame request header options for different sitecore sites?

Comment: You can do it in code, In a HttpRequest(End) Processor. And Context.Site give the current Sitecore Site object. but not clear what exactly you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to investigate `Sitecore.Context.Site` to accomplish this. `Sitecore.Context.Site.Name` should give you the value you need to discriminate by. I assume you already know how to set the request headers. Hope that answers your question!